# redirect after submiting post for review

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts, functions, redirect

I have a frontend page that allows "Tutor Instructor" role, to create a course and this course is a custom type post called courses, when the Tutor Instructor finishes creating the course he must click submit for review. when he clicks that button, the page will refresh and change the link to the editing link of the course (https://**************.com/dashboard/create-course/?course_ID=13865).

I want when the Tutor Instructor clicks submit for review the page redirects him to another page for example (https://**************.com/thank-you). How can I do that?

the code of the page

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_tutor_header( true );

    if ( wpse405644_is_frontend_editing_allowed() ) {
do_action( 'tutor_load_template_before', 'dashboard.create-course', null );
global $post;

$course_id          = get_the_ID();
$can_publish_course = (bool) tutor_utils()->get_option( 'instructor_can_publish_course' ) || current_user_can( 'administrator' );

if ( ! tutor_utils()->can_user_edit_course( get_current_user_id(), $course_id ) ) {
    tutor_load_template( 'permission-denied' );

    return;
}
?>

<?php do_action( 'tutor/dashboard_course_builder_before' ); ?>
    <form action="" id="tutor-frontend-course-builder" class="tutor-frontend-course-builder" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <?php wp_nonce_field( tutor()->nonce_action, tutor()->nonce ); ?>

        <header id="page-header" class="page-header header-dark header-sticky-dark-logo">
            <div class="page-header-place-holder"></div>
            <div id="page-header-inner" class="page-header-inner" data-sticky="1">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="header-wrap">
                        <div class="header-left">
                            <?php
                            $branding_args = [
                                'reverse_scheme' => true,
                            ];
                            ?>
                            <?php edumall_load_template( 'branding', null, $branding_args ); ?>

                            <button type="submit"
                                    class="tutor-dashboard-builder-draft-btn tutor-btn bordered-btn"
                                    name="course_submit_btn"
                                    value="save_course_as_draft">
                                <i class="fal fa-save"></i>
                                <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Save', 'edumall' ); ?></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="header-right">
                            <div class="header-content-inner">
                                <div id="header-right-inner" class="header-right-inner">
                                    <div class="header-right-inner-content">
                                        <?php Edumall_Templates::render_button( [
                                            'link'        => [
                                                'url'         => get_the_permalink( $course_id ),
                                                'is_external' => true,
                                            ],
                                            'text'        => esc_html__( 'Preview', 'edumall' ),
                                            'icon'        => 'fal fa-glasses',
                                            'extra_class' => 'button-grey',
                                        ] ); ?>

                                        <div class="form-submit">
                                            <?php if ( $can_publish_course ) : ?>
                                                <button class="tutor-button" type="submit"
                                                        name="course_submit_btn"
                                                        value="publish_course"><?php esc_html_e( 'Publish Course', 'edumall' ); ?></button>
                                            <?php else: ?>
                                                <button class="tutor-button" type="submit"
                                                        name="course_submit_btn"
                                                        value="submit_for_review"><?php esc_html_e( 'Submit for Review', 'edumall' ); ?></button>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="return-dashboard-link">
                                            <a href="<?php echo tutor_utils()->tutor_dashboard_url(); ?>"> <?php esc_html_e( 'Exit', 'edumall' ); ?></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <?php Edumall_Header::instance()->print_more_tools_button(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="tutor-frontend-course-builder-section tm-sticky-parent">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <input type="hidden" value="tutor_add_course_builder" name="tutor_action"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="course_ID" id="course_ID" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_ID" id="post_ID" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
                        <div class="tutor-dashboard-course-builder-wrap tm-sticky-column">

                            <!--since 1.8.0 alert message -->
                            <?php
                            $instructor_can_publish = tutils()->get_option( 'instructor_can_publish_course' );
                            ?>
                            <?php if ( current_user_can( 'tutor_instructor' ) && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) : ?>
                                <?php if ( isset( $_COOKIE['course_submit_for_review'] ) && ! $instructor_can_publish ) : ?>
                                    <div class="tutor-alert tutor-alert-info">
                                        <?php esc_html_e( 'Your course has been submitted to the admin. It will be published once it has been reviewed by the admins.', 'edumall' ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <!--alert message end -->

                            <?php do_action( 'tutor/dashboard_course_builder_form_field_before' ); ?>

                            <div class="tutor-course-builder-section tutor-course-builder-info">
                                <div class="tutor-course-builder-section-title">
                                    <h3>
                                        <i class="tutor-icon-down"></i><span><?php esc_html_e( 'Course Info', 'edumall' ); ?></span>
                                    </h3>
                                </div> <!--.tutor-course-builder-section-title-->
                                <div class="tutor-course-builder-section-content">
                                    <div class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                            <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Course Title', 'edumall' ); ?></label>
                                            <input type="text" name="title"
                                                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>"
                                                   placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'ex. Learn photoshop CS6 from scratch', 'edumall' ); ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!--.tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope-->

                                    <div class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                            <label> <?php esc_html_e( 'Description', 'edumall' ); ?></label>
                                            <?php
                                            $editor_settings = array(
                                                'media_buttons' => false,
                                                'quicktags'     => false,
                                                'editor_height' => 150,
                                                'textarea_name' => 'content',
                                            );
                                            wp_editor( $post->post_content, 'course_description', $editor_settings );
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  <!--.tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope-->

                                    <?php do_action( 'tutor/frontend_course_edit/after/description', $post ); ?>

                                    <div class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                            <label>
                                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Choose a category', 'edumall' ); ?>
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="tutor-form-field-course-categories">
                                                <?php //echo tutor_course_categories_checkbox($course_id);
                                                echo tutor_course_categories_dropdown( $course_id, array( 'classes' => 'tutor_select2' ) );
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                            <label>
                                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Choose a tag', 'edumall' ); ?>
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="tutor-form-field-course-tags">
                                                <?php //echo tutor_course_tags_checkbox($course_id);
                                                echo tutor_course_tags_dropdown( $course_id, array( 'classes' => 'tutor_select2' ) );
                                                ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php
                                    $monetize_by = tutils()->get_option( 'monetize_by' );
                                    if ( $monetize_by === 'wc' || $monetize_by === 'edd' ) {
                                        $course_price    = tutor_utils()->get_raw_course_price( get_the_ID() );
                                        $currency_symbol = tutor_utils()->currency_symbol();

                                        $_tutor_course_price_type = tutils()->price_type();
                                        ?>
                                        <div
                                            class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope tutor-frontend-builder-course-price">
                                            <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                                <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Course Price', 'edumall' ); ?></label>
                                                <div class="tutor-row tutor-align-items-center">
                                                    <div class="tutor-col-auto">
                                                        <label for="tutor_course_price_type_pro"
                                                               class="tutor-styled-radio">
                                                            <input id="tutor_course_price_type_pro" type="radio"
                                                                   name="tutor_course_price_type"
                                                                   value="paid" <?php $_tutor_course_price_type ? checked( $_tutor_course_price_type, 'paid' ) : checked( 'true', 'true' ); ?> >
                                                            <span></span>
                                                            <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                                            <span
                                                                class="tutor-input-prepand"><?php echo esc_html( $currency_symbol ); ?></span>
                                                                <input type="text" name="course_price"
                                                                       value="<?php echo esc_attr( $course_price->regular_price ); ?>"
                                                                       placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Set course price', 'edumall' ); ?>">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="tutor-col-auto">
                                                        <label class="tutor-styled-radio">
                                                            <input type="radio" name="tutor_course_price_type"
                                                                   value="free" <?php checked( $_tutor_course_price_type, 'free' ); ?> >
                                                            <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Free', 'edumall' ); ?></span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> <!--.tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope-->
                                    <?php } ?>

                                    <div class="tutor-frontend-builder-item-scope">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                            <label>
                                                <?php esc_html_e( 'Course Thumbnail', 'edumall' ); ?>
                                            </label>
                                            <div
                                                class="tutor-form-field tutor-form-field-course-thumbnail tutor-thumbnail-wrap">
                                                <div class="tutor-row tutor-align-items-center">
                                                    <div class="tutor-col-5">
                                                        <div class="builder-course-thumbnail-img-src">
                                                            <?php
                                                            $builder_course_img_src = tutor()->url . 'assets/images/placeholder-course.jpg';
                                                            $_thumbnail_url         = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $course_id );
                                                            $post_thumbnail_id      = get_post_thumbnail_id( $course_id );

                                                            if ( ! $_thumbnail_url ) {
                                                                $_thumbnail_url = $builder_course_img_src;
                                                            }
                                                            ?>
                                                            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $_thumbnail_url ); ?>"
                                                                 class="thumbnail-img"
                                                                 data-placeholder-src="<?php echo esc_url( $builder_course_img_src ); ?>">
                                                            <a href="javascript:;"
                                                               class="tutor-course-thumbnail-delete-btn"
                                                               style="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( 'display: %s;', $post_thumbnail_id ? 'block' : 'none' ) ); ?>">
                                                                <i class="tutor-icon-line-cross"></i>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="tutor-col-7">
                                                        <div class="builder-course-thumbnail-upload-wrap">
                                                            <p class="builder-course-thumbnail-guide-line">
                                                                <?php echo sprintf( __( "Important Guideline: %1\$s 700x430 pixels %2\$s %3\$s File Support: %1\$s .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, or .png %2\$s no text on the image.", 'edumall' ), "<strong>", "</strong>", "<br>" ); ?>
                                                            </p>
                                                            <input type="hidden" id="tutor_course_thumbnail_id"
                                                                   name="tutor_course_thumbnail_id"
                                                                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post_thumbnail_id ); ?>">
                                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);"
                                                               class="tutor-course-thumbnail-upload-btn tutor-button bordered-button"><?php esc_html_e( 'Upload Image', 'edumall' ); ?></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <?php do_action( 'tutor/dashboard_course_builder_form_field_after', $post ); ?>

                            <div class="tutor-form-row tutor-form-submit">
                                <div class="tutor-form-col-12">
                                    <div class="tutor-form-group">
                                        <div class="tutor-form-field tutor-course-builder-btn-group">
                                            <button type="submit" class="tutor-button btn-save-as-draft"
                                                    name="course_submit_btn"
                                                    value="save_course_as_draft"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save course as draft', 'edumall' ); ?></button>
                                            <?php if ( $can_publish_course ) :  ?>
                                                <button class="tutor-button tutor-success" type="submit"
                                                        name="course_submit_btn"
                                                        value="publish_course"><?php esc_html_e( 'Publish Course', 'edumall' ) ; ?></button>
                                            <?php else : ?>
                                                <button class="tutor-button tutor-success" type="submit"
                                                        name="course_submit_btn"
                                                        value="submit_for_review"><?php esc_html_e( 'Submit for Review', 'edumall' );  ?></button>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="tutor-course-builder-upload-tips tm-sticky-column">
                            <h3 class="tutor-course-builder-tips-title">
                                <i class="far fa-lightbulb-on"></i><?php esc_html_e( 'Course Upload Tips', 'edumall' ); ?>
                            </h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Set the Course Price option or make it free.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Standard size for course thumbnail is 700x430.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Video section controls the course overview video.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Course Builder is where you create & organize a course.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Add Topics in the Course Builder section to create lessons, quizzes, and assignments.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Prerequisites refers to the fundamental courses to complete before taking this particular course.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Information from the Additional Data section shows up on the course single page.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                                <li><?php esc_html_e( 'Make Announcements to notify any important notes to all enrolled students at once.', 'edumall' ); ?></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>



<?php do_action( 'tutor/dashboard_course_builder_after' ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'tutor_load_template_after', 'dashboard.create-course', null ); ?>
<?php
    } else {
        echo '<h2>You are not allowed to edit this post.</h2>';
    } ?>
<?php get_tutor_footer( true );
```

Comment: If that form is being submitted through AJAX, you will need to look for any events that takes place and use that to redirect using JS. If the form submitted normally, check the function that handles the form submission. If this is a plugin, you better ask the developer.

Comment: i don't know if this submitted through AJAX. It's a plugin, and the theme made this frontend. The developers don't have any ideas on how to do that. You can see that here (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-after-creating-a-course/). if you need to see what is the file let me know but the file has more than 7K line.

Comment: If that page doesn't redirect/reloads after submit, then it should be using AJAX to submit. Look for the JavaScript function that handles the code and hook into success event. Cant help more as discussion on the third-party plugins/themes is off-topic here.

Comment: The tutor will be here while creating the course (https://**********.net/dashboard/create-course). After submitting, the page will redirect/reload to (https:///**********.net/dashboard/create-course/?course_ID=13880) "depending on what the course_ID" this page is where he can edit anything in his course. It's the same page but the link changed.

Comment: As I said, you need to add a few lines on code in the AJAX handler.

Comment: How can I do that? I don't know how to work with AJAX; at least, I want to show a message, alert box, or alert message to tell the tutor that we have received this course.